# Load a shapefile into geopandas from a request.files

Tags: python, shapefile, fiona, request, files

I'm trying to receive a simple `.shp` file, without been zipped, via web request and convert it to a geopandas dataframe. I tried to use io.BytesIO to wrap the file but also didn't worked.. I tried to load directly to geopandas but this is what happened:

```
File "fiona/_shim.pyx", line 81, in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector

fiona.errors.DriverError: '/vsimem/9ead9a26f6de48e987cc6474e377012b/9ead9a26f6de48e987cc6474e377012b' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

The code:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

...

file = request.files[filename]
 
if file and allowed_file(filename):
    geo2 = gpd.read_file(file)
    print(geo2)
```

Comment: Shapefiles have at least three components. .shp without .dbf isn't of much use.

Comment: @Vince thank you for your answering but I trying to replicate the same as I have where I'm reading the file locally and then converting to geoJSON.

Comment: What exactly is returned from this request? It should be a zipped file containing a shp, dbf, and shx files.

Comment: Only a `.shp`. Thank you @LeonPowałka, Since the geopandas.read_file() only requires the path for the `.shp`  I thought was not necessary the corresponding dbf and shx files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you only pass the `.shp` filepath to `geopandas.read_file()`, geopandas requires the corresponding `.dbf` and `.shx` files to exist and determines their paths relative to the `.shp`.